# Python - pywin32, object has no attribute 'AddChart'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pywin32

I am trying to embed a chart inside an Excel sheet, I was able to find information on stackoverflow about using the AddChart function, however I get this error:

```
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 10.0 Object Library._Worksheet instance at 0x25233328>' object has no attribute 'AddChart'
```

Is there a way to fix this ?

EDIT: Here is my code

```
xlLeft, xlRight, xlCenter = -4131, -4152, -4108 

import win32com.client
from win32com.client import constants as c

xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True

Workbook = xl.Workbooks.Add()
Sheets = Workbook.Sheets

print "Debut"

Sheets(1).Range("A1:D1").Merge()
Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Test"
Sheets(1).Range("A1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

tableSize = 4

for y in xrange(1,tableSize):
    for x in xrange(0,tableSize):
            Sheets(1).Cells(y+1, x+1).Value = y*x

test = Sheets(1).Rows("1:1")
test.Interior.ColorIndex = 15

Sheets(1).Range("A2:D4").Select()

ch = xl.Sheets(1).AddChart()
ch.SetSourceData(Sheets(1).Range("A2:D4"))
ch.ChartType = c.xlLine

print "Fin"
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

`AddChart` is a [member of the `Shapes` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238877%28v=office.12%29.aspx).  So:

```
xl.Sheets(1).Shapes.AddChart();
```